# Purchasing power of US dollar during its history

Tags: united-states, purchasing-power-partity

Is there an online tool to calculate how many goods (and which ones, of course) I could buy in a specific year in the past, e.g., 1792, 1800, 1810, 1820, and so on for a given number of US dollars?

Something similar to the [calculator by the British National Archives](https://www.nationalarchives.gov.uk/currency-converter/).

> ```
> 10 pounds and 5 shillings, 1650
> ```
>
> [image]